# extract fields to variable

Tags: bash

I want to extract the fields from a line into variables:

```
aaa bbb ccc
```

'aaa' => $a, 'bbb' => $b, 'ccc' => $c. How to do it in bash?

I don't want to pipeline the processing, just need to extract them to variables or array.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can simply do:

```
read a b c <<<"aaa bbb ccc"
```

#### OUTPUT

```
$ echo "a=[$a] b=[$b] c=[$c]"
a=[aaa] b=[bbb] c=[ccc]
```

As per bash manual:

```
   Here Strings
       A variant of here documents, the format is:
              <<<word
       The word is expanded and supplied to the command on its standard input.
```

Comment: what's the difference between "read a b c <<<"aaa bbb ccc"" and "echo aaa bbb ccc | read a b c"?

Comment: @Todd: `echo aaa bbb ccc | read a b c` doesn't even work in bash even `echo aaa | read x` doesn't work.

Comment: it's strange because echo aaa | while read x; do $echo $x; done  is OK.

Comment: That does ok but $x is not available outside while loop. If you try to echo $x outside you will empty value.

Answer (score 5):

The simplest is:

```
read a b c
```

with I/O redirection from where the line is being read:

```
while read a b c
do
    # Process
done < $some_file
```

If the data is already in a variable, then you could use:

```
read a b c < <(echo "$variable")
```

This uses a Bash-specific feature, process substitution.